# Python не хочет создавать сетевой мост

Tags: python, сеть, paramiko, tunnel

Хочу сделать свой сетевой тоннель используя python.
Для этого я создал 2 виртуальные машины Ubuntu, сделал им подключение через сетевой мост (использую VmWare).

Это клиентская часть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import socket

host = '192.168.1.104'
port = 8888

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
client_socket.connect((host, port))

while True:
    message = input("Введите сообщение->")
    if message == 'q':
        break
    client_socket.send(message.encode())

    response = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(response.decode())

    client_socket.send("Сообщение успешно принято!".encode())

client_socket.close()
```

Это серверная часть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import paramiko
import threading


def handle_client(client_socket):
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break

        response = "Принято: " + data.decode()
        client_socket.senddall(response.encode())
    client_socket.close()


# 192.168.1.106


def start_tunnel():
    host = '192.168.1.105'
    port = 8888

    server_socket = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
    server_socket.load_server_moduli()
    try:
        server_socket.add_server_key(paramiko.RSAKey.generate(2048))
    except paramiko.SSHException:
        print("Ошибка генерации ключей")
        return

    server = SSHServer()
    try:
        server_socket.start_server(server=server)
    except paramiko.SSHException as e:
        print("Ошибка запуска SSH сервера: ", str(e))
        return

    print("Сервер ожидает подключения по порту ", port)

    while True:
        client_socket = server_socket.accept(20)
        if client_socket is None:
            continue

        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
        client_thread.start()


class SSHServer(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        if kind == "session":
            return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
        return paramiko.OPEN_FAILED_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED

    def check_auth_password(self, username: str, password: str):
        return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL



start_tunnel()
```

Возникает такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/serverTunnel/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    client_socket.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

она возникает как на клиентской, как на серверной части.

Так же я пробовал использовать windows, как клиент

В свою очередь он выдает такую ошибку. (Порты в брандмауэре я открыл)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MyProgramProjects\tunnelProject\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    client_socket.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
```